# ford figo 2012 pretrol starting problem

Tags: ford, figo

I replace my ignition barrel on ford figo 2012.

The key light doesn’t blink, so its is reading the key and also when turning the key its makes 8 beeps.

The problem that I have is when trying to start the engine (turning the key) it only makes a clicking noise at the engine.

My radio speaker makes a noise when I turn the key to start the engine.

The ABS light on the dashboard is permanently on when the ignition is on.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I'm reading this correctly, the key will turn to the "on" position where everything lights up, but if you turn it further, you can't get to the "start" position, where it would crank the engine?

Comment: it does turn to the start position  just makes a clicking sound at the engine, battery is fully charged

Comment: Check your battery cables at both ends to make sure they have good connections and there's no corrosion. What you are describing tells me there's a poor connection somewhere not allowing the power to flow. Enough to get the radio to work, but once you put the starter in motion, there's not enough.

Comment: I have made some changes to your text.  Can you check that the changes are correct?

Comment: thanks you!!!!!!!!